# Método Uppercase para Metroframework

Tags: c#, metroframework

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de ajuda em `TextBox`, onde trabalho em `c#` usando [Metroframework](http://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/).

Preciso transformar todo o texto digitado nos `TextBox` em letras maiúsculas. Como posso fazer?

Comment: Já tentou usar o método `.ToUpper()` ?

Comment: Entao para todos os textbox eu uso esse metodo ?!

Comment: Mais uma coisa...onde eu incluo esse metodo no meu form ? Desculpe , sou novo em c#

Comment: quero que todos os dados inclusos no formulario de cadastro , por exemplo " cadastro de clientes" ja aparecem maiusculos , quando forem digitados nos textbox

Comment: ou seja, que apareçam no textbox ja maiúsculas

Comment: Sim, estou usando WinForms

Comment: @RennanHanna, Atualizei minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Se o Framework fosse para `Xaml/WPF`:

No `Xaml` de onde está o botão, existe a propriedade `CharacterCasing` que aceita os seguintes valores: `Upper`, `Lower` e `Normal`.

Setando esta propriedade ao botão diretamente no `xaml`

```
<TextBox  CharacterCasing="Upper" />
```

No momento que o usuário for digitar, as letras já apareceram em maiúsculo.
E quando você for recuperar o valor do `TextBox` no `codebehind` ele já vira em maiúsculo.

Outra maneira de setar seria no `codebehind`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NomeTextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
}
```

**O `MetroFrameWork`realmente não suporta essa propriedade. Então vão algumas sugestões:**

1 - Você pode usar o `ToUpper()`, para colocar as letras em maiúsculas antes de jogar os dados para o `BD`.

2 - Comece usar `WPF`, é mais avançado em relação ao `WinForms`, e te da mais liberdade para criar. [Site](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) recomendado para começar.

3 - No visual studio 2015, você pode criar `apps/programas` com estilo metro já por padrão, dispensando uso de `frameworks`.  - [Noticia](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/microsoft/24157-microsoft-corta-funcoes-e-prioriza-aplicativos-metro-em-novo-visual-studio.htm) falando sobre isso.

4 - FrameWork para ´WPF´ [Mahapps](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html).

5 - Não sei o seu nível de conhecimento, mas se estiver começando, aprenda como funciona para depois usar `frameworks`, e comece por `WPF`, pois a própria microsoft recomenda o uso, pois `WinForms` está ficando para trás.

Comment: Pois é , justamente! Não existe CharacterCasing nas propriedades, por eu estar desenvolvendo em Metaframework.

Comment: Qual a diferença entre winforms e wfp MeuChapeu?

Comment: @RennanHanna, de uma lida neste [Artigo](http://blog.lambda3.com.br/2010/01/wpf-ou-windows-forms/) do site Lambda3. Ele explica bem certinho, é de 2010, mas tah valendo.

Comment: vou verificar , muito obrigado MeuChapeu

Answer (score 2):

Para facilitar a vida e não ter necessidade de criar o método em todas os `Forms`, você pode criar um novo controle que herda desse `TextBox` que está utilizando e nele você inclui o método indicado na resposta do nosso amigo *jbueno*.
Exemplo:

```
class TextBoxEx : TextBox 
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
            e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é alterar o evento `KeyPress` do teu `TextBox` para transformar todas as letras em maiúsculas.

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper());
}
```

Talvez o mais viável no teu caso, seria criar um novo componente que herde o `MetroTextBox`, ai tu podes sobrescrever (`override`) essa função e, inclusive, criar uma propriedade com o mesmo intuito de `CharacterCasing` para que seja possível escolher na *property window* se tu queres que ele seja *case sensitive* ou não.

Comment: Que complicação, mas, por mais que seja demorado , vou ter que fazer um por  um em todos os textbox de todos os forms, pois nao sei fazer isso que sugeriu ! rs

Comment: Se tu der uma pesquisada por `UserControl` ou componentes personalizados tu vais achar **muito** material.

Comment: Vou procurar , valeu Jeferson